# How to write a string type that does not contain an empty string in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

A function of TypeScript wroten as below:

```
function propKeyMap(propKey:string):string {
  //TODO
}
```

The `propKey` can't be an  `""`(empty string). Can we write a type which does not contain an empty string?

Comment: Do you need the check at runtime? Then a type restriction is the wrong choice.

Comment: I do believe, this should be possible to achieve. Not sure how, yet :). Anyway, take a look on this discussion on GitHub https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14833 It may be helpful starting point to understand, how to write such NonEmptyString type.

Comment: That issue says that Typescript's Type System is Turing Complete, which means this task can be done, but however, TypeScript doesn't do runtime checks, meaning that it doesn't know if the variable is an empty string or not unless the string is a constant.

Answer (score 15):

Note: this answer was written before [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) and [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) existed and is therefore obsolete (although there are still no subtraction types and so no specific type corresponds to `string & not ""`).  [The other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69252250/2887218) talks about newer workarounds, so I won't belabor them in this answer.

Old answer follows:

---

No, you can't do this.  Just check the `propKey` value at runtime and throw an error if it is empty.

TypeScript currently (as of v2.5) lacks [subtraction types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4183), so there's no way to tell the compiler that a type is a `string` but not `""`.  There are, however, workarounds.

You can use *branding* (see discussion in [Microsoft/TypeScript #4895](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4895)) to create a subtype of `string`, and then try to enforce the non-empty constraint yourself, because TypeScript can't.  For example:

```
type NonEmptyString = string & { __brand: 'NonEmptyString' };
```

Now, you can't just assign a `string` value to a `NonEmptyString` variable:

```
const nope: NonEmptyString = 'hey'; // can't assign directly
```

But you can create a function which takes a `string` and returns a `NonEmptyString`:

```
function nonEmptyString(str: ""): never;
function nonEmptyString(str: string): NonEmptyString;
function nonEmptyString(str: string): NonEmptyString {
  if (str === '')
    throw new TypeError('empty string passed to nonEmptyString()');
  return str as NonEmptyString;
}
```

The function `nonEmptyString()` will blow up at runtime if you pass in an empty `string`, so as long as you only construct `NonEmptyString` objects with this function, you are safe.  Additionally, if TypeScript knows for a fact that you've passed in an empty string, the returned object will be of type `never` (essentially meaning that it shouldn't happen).  So it can do a little bit of compile-time guarding against empty strings:

```
const okay = nonEmptyString('hey');
okay.charAt(0); // still a string

const oops = nonEmptyString(''); // will blow up at runtime
oops.charAt(0); // TypeScript knows that this is an error
```

But it really is just a *little* bit of compile-time guarding, since there are many times when TypeScript doesn't realize that a `string` is empty:

```
const empty: string = ""; // you've hidden from TS the fact that empty is ""
const bigOops = nonEmptyString(empty); // will blow up at runtime
bigOops.charAt(0); // TypeScript doesn't realize that it will blow up
```

Still, it's better than nothing... or it might be.  The bottom line is that you probably need to do compile time assertions with runtime checks for the empty string, no matter what.

Even if TypeScript could express `NonEmptyString` natively as something like `string - ""`, the compiler probably wouldn't be smart enough in most cases to deduce that the result of a string manipulation was or was not a `NonEmptyString`.  I mean, *we* know that a concatenation of two `NonEmptyString`s should have a length of at least two, but I doubt TypeScript would:

```
declare let x: NonEmptyString; 
declare let y: NonEmptyString; 
const secondCharBad: NonEmptyString = (x + y).charAt(1); // won't work
const secondCharGood = nonEmptyString((x + y).charAt(1)); // okay
```

That's because the type you're asking for is near the very top of the slippery slope down to [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), which are great for developer expressivity, but not great for compiler decidability.  Probably something reasonable could be done at the type level for non-empty strings, but in general you'll still find yourself needing to help the compiler decide when strings are actually non-empty.

---

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Is there any possible someday a rewrote version of typescript will be a language with dependent type such as Idris?

Answer (score 14):

### Solution using template literal types

Since TypeScript 4.1 you can achive this using [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types). However, it's a bit verbose, because you have to define a union type of all possible strings of length 1:

```
type Character = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | ...;
type NonEmptyString = `${Character}${string}`;
```

### Solution using conditional types

There's another solution (prior to 4.1) too using conditional types and a generic:

```
type NonEmptyString<T extends string> = '' extends T ? never : T;
function propKeyMap<T extends string>(propKey: NonEmptyString<T>): string {
  //TODO
}
```

This solution is useful for functions as you don't have to explicitly specify the generic when calling it. However, when using it anywhere else you'd have to define the generic which then will just make it the same type you use for the generic:

```
let x: NonEmptyString<'foo'>; // This is of type 'foo'
let y: NonEmptyString<string>; //This is of type never
```

Likewise, it is not possible to pass a string to the function (which is correct, as string includes an empty string). But this fact, combined with the lack of possibility to type variables as NonEmptyString, means, that this is only useful for functions that will directly be called with string literals rather than variables.

```
propKeyMap('foo'); // Compiles (as expected)
propKeyMap('');    // Errors   (as expected)

const x: 'foo' = 'foo';
propKeyMap(x);     // Compiles (as expected)

const y: string = 'foo';
propKeyMap(y);     // Errors   (unexpected)
```

For cases where this limitation is acceptable, I'd recommend this solution though, as it doesn't include defining the cumbersome union type required fo the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using branded types:

```
interface NonEmptyString<S extends string = string> {
    __nonEmptyString: true
    value: S
}

type NonEmptyStringResult<S extends string = string> =
S extends ''
    ? never
    : NonEmptyString<S>

function nonEmptyString<S extends string>(s: S): NonEmptyStringResult<S> {
    if (s === '') {
        throw new Error('s is empty');
    }
    return {
        __nonEmptyString: true,
        value: s
    } as any;
}

function greet(s: NonEmptyString) {
    console.log('Hello ' + s.value)
}

const isNotEmpty = nonEmptyString('Hello');
greet(isNotEmpty);

const isEmpty = nonEmptyString('');
greet(isEmpty);
```

Comment: This answer would be better with more explanation and examples. See the other answers for expected level of detail. For instance, it seems I have to call the function `nonEmptyString` before passing my string to a function expecting a `NonEmptyString`. Why? Can I use the `isNotEmpty` variable just like a normal string? Does `isNotEmpty == 'Hello'` return true?