# How to narrow number type to omit NaN, -Infinity, +Infinity

Tags: typescript

for example `isPositive` predicate from `ramda-adjunct`

```
RA.isPositive(1); // => true
RA.isPositive(Number.MAX_VALUE); // => true
RA.isPositive(-Infinity); // => false
RA.isPositive(NaN); // => false
RA.isPositive('5'); // => false
```

has type `isPositive(val: any): val is number`

but number is still including `NaN, -Infinity, +Infinity`, how to omit them?

Comment: Why do you want to do so, and how would you use it? These are valid numeric values.you might as well ask how to narrow the type to not include 2 and 7.

Comment: lol) just want to know is it possible, seems not

Comment: This is a near-duplicate of ["How to write a string type that does not contain an empty string in TypeScript"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46253340/how-to-write-a-string-type-that-does-not-contain-an-empty-string-in-typescript/46255250#46255250); maybe my answer there will help you.  Just replace `string` with `number` and `""` with `Infinity | -Infinity | NaN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may treat your requirement as dealing with [primitive obsession](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/25/DesignSmellPrimitiveObsession/) and encapsulate this kind of number into a `FiniteNumber` type with the corresponding guard clauses in the constructor and the `valueOf()` method to allow arithmetic operations:

```js
class FiniteNumber {
    constructor(public value: number) {
        if (!isFinite(value)) {
            throw new RangeError(`Expecting finite number`);
        }
    }

    valueOf() {
        return this.value;
    }
}

const n2 = new FiniteNumber(2);
console.log(n2); // → FiniteNumber { value: 2 }
console.log(1 + n2.value); // → 3
console.log(1 + <any>n2); // → 3
console.log(new FiniteNumber(NaN)); // → Uncaught RangeError: Expecting finite number
```

→ Code in action through the [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20FiniteNumber%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20value%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!isFinite(value))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20RangeError(%60Expecting%20finite%20number%60)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20valueOf()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20n2%20%3D%20new%20FiniteNumber(2)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(n2)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%E2%86%92%20FiniteNumber%20%7B%20value%3A%202%20%7D%0D%0Aconsole.log(1%20%2B%20n2.value)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%E2%86%92%203%0D%0Aconsole.log(1%20%2B%20%3Cany%3En2)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%E2%86%92%203%0D%0Aconsole.log(new%20FiniteNumber(NaN))%3B%20%2F%2F%20%E2%86%92%20Uncaught%20RangeError%3A%20Expecting%20finite%20number%0D%0A).

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible with the way type constraints are in TypeScript.

You will need runtime guards against those specific values.

Comment: to extend this answer: there is a proposal which will make it possible https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28682